# Referencing Common Files Beyond Where Domain Points

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

Let's assume I have an unlimited hosting plan on GoDaddy that I want to use for 3 different sites. We'll call them "Site One," "Site Two," and "Site Three."

So in my root of my unlimited hosting package, I will have all three sites, each represented by a folder. I'd like to have a fourth folder for files common to ALL the sites. For example, the root might look like this:

```
[site_one folder]
[site_two folder]
[site_three folder]
[common folder]
```

So, let's suppose www.siteOne.com points directly to [site_one folder], and all the contents of that site live in that folder.

It does not seem possible to go back BEYOND the siteOne folder by piling up dots like this:

```
 ../../../common_folder/myImage.jpg
```

to access a file in my common folder. It seems you can only go back to the directory where the domain points.

Is there a way to do this that's considered a good practice?

All three sites will share the same mySQL database, which I don't think is a problem, because they usually have direct addresses to a SQL host. Correct?

But, could I use, say, a common "upload" folder for all three sites and be able to reference the files in it? Would I have to set up some kind of Global variable to hold a server path?

Can anyone help? I will be working in PHP.

Comment: I'd usually work with a 4th domain (for instance, _'statics.example.com'_, or _'cdn.example.com'_ if it is one). The mentioned symlink would also work though, but no benefit of caching for all 3 domains in 1 go.

Comment: Thanks, Wrikken. This is the route I am going to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an `uploads` folder above each site (like you described with the [common folder] then create a symlink to that folder inside each site, which points at `../uploads`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Joe. I tried working with a symlink, but GoDaddy told me they didn't think it would work. You're probably right that it would, but I'll use the extra domain instead, since I'm having trouble configuring it on their server.